# Where to store refresh_token for SPA/REST app with third-party OAuth2 service?

Tags: javascript, security, rest, oauth

I have an client (SPA)/server (REST) application and I need to authenticate clients and keep them logged in in the resource server.
The application in general has to use external OAuth2 service located on third-party authorization server.
Now the question: where refresh_token should be stored? I have two ideas.

I intentionally omit the case when refresh_token expires.

## Assumptions

- Valid token is always returned in response to the request to any secured resource and the login request.
- All communication with the authorization server must go through the resource server since client_id and client_secret are required.

## First Scenario

1. Server stores refresh_token mapped by token and **sends the token** to the client with response to login request.
2. Client makes a request with a token.
3. Server checks if the token is valid. If not it uses the refresh_token associated with the token to generate a new one. Now for one minute (or any configured duration) old token is mapped to the new token and the new token is mapped to refresh_token to handle enqueued requests with the old token.
4. Client makes a request with a token.
5. Server checks if the token is valid. If not it checks if token is mapped to the new one. If so it behaves like request was send with the new token (see step 3). It sends 401 otherwise.

## Second Scenario

1. Server **sends the token and the refresh_token** to the client with response to login request.
2. Client makes a request with a token.
3. Server checks if the token is valid. If not it responds with 401.
4. If client consumes response with 401 status it tries to refresh the token and makes the same request with the new token.

I'm aware that both of these solutions has their weaknesses. Is there any good practice applicable to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access-token and refresh-token should stay where they have been fetched,  especially if you are not using HTTPS for your backend.

SPA without own REST backend should use OAuth implicit flow to get the access-token. Refresh tokens are not supported for implicit flow.

Applications with a server-side backend should use authorization code flow (your case). Authorization code is exchanged to access and refresh tokens by the backend and should stay there. Your REST backend can use access-token to access third-party resources and refresh-token to renew access-token when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The second scenario seems to me the most viable one. First, your authorization server does not have to be the same as your resource server. You only use the refresh token to get a new access token from the authorization server. But the authorization server and resource server could both be implemented in the same server.

How would the client in the first scenario get the new access token back? It was requesting a resource (step 3) and does not expect to get back a new token.

I would store the refresh token at the client side in browser local storage or something. This is not highly secure, but probably the best you can do.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As it is denoted in the question - authorization server is a third-party so it isn't collocated with the resource server. I assumed that the valid token is always returned in Authorization header of the response to request to secured resource. That's how client gets the new token back. I also haven't mentioned that communication with the authorization server must go trough the resource server because the first one requires client_id and secret, which can't be hold by the client app. I'll edit my question to make that clear.

Comment: I hope this will clear your doubts http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27966775/revisions

Comment: The Authorization header is an HTTP request header. You should not be sending it in a response. Typically, both access token and refresh token are returned as a JSON response from the authorization server.